# Plsql adding item to array won't workout

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql

I need to add an item to an array but this isn't working out at all.

Code:

```
DECLARE
  ..
  TYPE textGroupArray IS VARRAY(6) OF VARCHAR(4);
  textGroups textGroupArray;
  arrayCount  NUMBER;
  ..
BEGIN
  ..
  textGroups := textGroupArray(10);
  arrayCount  := 0;
  ..
  IF textGroup != 0 THEN
     arrayCount := arrayCount + 1;
     textGroups( arrayCount ) := textGroup;
  END IF;
```

For somereason I can't figure out, Oracle isn't adding anything into the array..

(The error i get)
[image]

**P.S.**
I already tried a lot tho, no hate for being a newby please. Just started learning plSql.

**P.S.S.**
If you don't approve my post format, please submit a edit so I can learn form that.

**P.S.S.S**
If you need some extra information. I will happily add this for you!

Thanks!

[Code snippit](http://pastebin.ca/3264290)

Comment: The error is occurring at line 53. Which line is that in your code snippet?

Comment: Also, could you post a complete and verifiable code sample that exhibits the behaviour you're seeing? Thanks.

Comment: Hello Darwin, codesnippit is coming in about 20 seconds!

Comment: in #line6  you declared `textGroup   as VARCHAR2(50);` but textGroupArray  is declared as `VARRAY(6) OF VARCHAR(4);` to fix this change this to  `VARRAY(6) OF VARCHAR(50);`

Comment: Please don't refer to external resources, instead add the code to the question. When the external resource disappears (and it will disappear at some day) the question makes no more sense. Also don't include text as image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of VARRAY is wrong.

First try to change your output like this

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'textGroup: <'||textGroup||'>' );

Output is

textGroup: < 3536>
textGroup: < 2029>
textGroup: < 2712>
textGroup: < 3456>
textGroup: < 789>
textGroup: <>
```

So `TYPE textGroupArray IS VARRAY(6) OF VARCHAR(4);` is not sufficient, you should use `TYPE textGroupArray IS VARRAY(6) OF VARCHAR2(5);` or use `textGroups( arrayCount ) := TRIM(textGroup);`

NB, it is not recommended to use datatype `VARCHAR`. Use `VARCHAR2` instead.

Then `textGroups := textGroupArray(10);` does not set the size of your varray to 10 (which would not be possible anyway, because the max size is only 6). It sets the first element to '10'.

Proper initialization is for example:

```
textGroups := textGroupArray(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

Comment: Hello Wernfiend. Thansk for you help! I made some stupid mistakes I see, like trying and set this length (10) when is (6) is only possible, and the length of 1 element to (4) when the elements where (5), including the spacing. Is it posible to set each item on its own? Like textGroep(index) := 'Something', textGroep(index++) := 'Something els'? Instead of setting it in once. Because I need to loop and depending on the loop, fill a array

Comment: You can use a nested table, i.e. `TYPE textGroupArray TABLE OF VARCHAR2(5); textGroups textGroupArray := textGroupArray();` and `textGroups.EXTEND; textGroups(textGroups.LAST) := textGroup;`

Comment: Wernfried, I posted a new question. Maybee you can help me here 2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33846380/plsql-return-associative-array-function